# Symfony2 translation pluralization arabic language

Tags: symfony, translation, arabic

I have a problem with pluralization translation in symfony2 in my arabic yaml file.

I can't write interval correctly it always shuffle and give me error. I don't seem to find a way to write the sentence correcty because it always changes after I add a number and it become like this `شخص|]1,Inf] أشخاص`
please help me am really stuck!

```yaml
recent: الأحدث 
popular: الأكثر شعبية 
Next: التالي 
January: يناير 
February: فبراير 
March: مارس 
April: أبريل 
May: ماي 
June: يونيو 
July: يوليوز 
August: غشت 
September: شتنبر 
October: أكتوبر 
November: نونبر 
December: دجنبر 
You: أنتم 
And: و 
PERSON: شخص واحد 
PERSONS: أشخاص
PERSON_PERSONS: شخص|]1,Inf] أشخاص 
Print: طباعة
```

Comment: can you provide your `yml` file?

Comment: recent: الأحدث
popular: الأكثر شعبية
Next: التالي
January: يناير
February: فبراير
March: مارس
April: أبريل
May: ماي
June: يونيو
July: يوليوز
August: غشت
September: شتنبر
October: أكتوبر
November: نونبر
December: دجنبر
You: أنتم
And: و
PERSON: شخص واحد
PERSONS: أشخاص
PERSON_PERSONS:شخص|]1,Inf] أشخاص
Print: طباعة

Answer (score 1):

Thanks ferdynator i found the mistake i was making it's not about the letters shuffling it got interpreted , the problem was that i didn't manage all cases of pluralization i should add case {1}, solved!